# How long does it take for Google to stop indexing pages included in robots.txt file?

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I have some unnecessary files on my website and want to stop showing it on Google search results. So I have included that file in robots.txt file like,

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /cache/
```

The files had been using in the website long ago and now it's not necessary.

So if I add the file in robots.txt file, will Google remove the page from index and stop showing them on SERP? If so how long does it take?

Answer (score 2):

From [Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq#h18):

> #### How long will it take for changes in my robots.txt file to affect my search results?
>
> First, the cache of the robots.txt file must be refreshed (we generally cache the contents for up to one day). Even after finding the change, crawling and indexing is a complicated process that can sometimes take quite some time for individual URLs, so it's impossible to give an exact timeline. Also, keep in mind that even if your robots.txt file is disallowing access to a URL, that URL may remain visible in search results despite that fact that we can't crawl it. **If you wish to expedite removal of the pages you've blocked from Google, please submit a removal request via [Google Search Console](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).**

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear Derek, If we remove the particular folder from server still will it show on the search results? Because we have lot of pages on that folder, So it's not possible for us to remove all the pages individually. Thank you

Comment: You can probably submit a removal request of a directory on the Google Search Console. Take a look at that and see what happens.

Comment: Oh really thank you so much Derek, I didn't aware of this before. I shall try it and get back to you :)